# Unity WWW Class on Android Doesnt Work

Tags: android, mobile, unity-game-engine

I have this simple gui script that opens a url when clicked. I dont need to actually open the url in browser, because it is just an adress to a php file. The code works fine when I tried in PC, but nothing happened when I run it on Android device.

Here is the code:

```
#pragma strict

var one = "192.168.0.125:8888/one";
var two = "192.168.0.125:8888/two";
Var three = "192.168.0.125:8888/three";
Var all = "192.168.0.125:8888/all";
function Start () {

}

function Update () {
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}

function OnGUI () {

if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,20,300, 75), "ONE")) {
   var ONE_ : WWW = new WWW(one);
}

else if(GUI.Button  (Rect(20,200,300, 75), "TWO")){
    var TWO_ : WWW = new WWW(two);
    }

else if(GUI.Button  (Rect(20,380,300, 75), "THREE")){
    var THREE_ : WWW = new WWW(three);
    }

else if(GUI.Button  (Rect(20,560,300, 75), "ALL")){
    var ALL_ : WWW = new WWW(all);
    }

}
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not waiting for the WWW class to finish the request.

You need to declare the WWW class in a different method (or make it a class var) and use the yield syntax to wait for it.

Your code should look something like this:

```
#pragma strict

var one = "192.168.0.125:8888/one";
var two = "192.168.0.125:8888/two";
var three = "192.168.0.125:8888/three";
var all = "192.168.0.125:8888/all";
function Start () {

}

function Update () {
 Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}

function CreateWWW(address)
{
  var wwwAccess : WWW = new WWW(address);
  yield wwwAccess;
}

function OnGUI () {

 if (GUI.Button (Rect (20,20,300, 75), "ONE")) {
  CreateWWW(one);
}

else if(GUI.Button  (Rect(20,200,300, 75), "TWO")){
 CreateWWW(two);
 }

 else if(GUI.Button  (Rect(20,380,300, 75), "THREE")){
 CreateWWW(three);
 }

 else if(GUI.Button  (Rect(20,560,300, 75), "ALL")){
  CreateWWW(all);
 }

}
```

Here's the link to the Unity [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

Also, you don't need to specify the orientation on each update, you can set it from PlayerSettings->Resolution and Presentation->Allowed orientations for Auto Rotation.